# How to get a YouTube video thumbnail using API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube

I need to put a YouTube video in my site. This is video URL:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLx0NuvoQ5jfdEvOCFa8kRnfg5S7F3t_93&v=I-tBhNwVa7w

How can I get the thumbnail using the API?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eh85q74b/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get your image using this url .  In this tutorial "I-tBhNwVa7w" is YouTube vidio ID . you can replace it with other video ID.

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/0.jpg (full size).
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/1.jpg (thumbnail).
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/2.jpg (thumbnail).
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/3.jpg (thumbnail).

http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/maxresdefault.jpg  (maximum resolution ).
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/sddefault.jpg (standard default).
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/mqdefault.jpg (medium quality).
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/hqdefault.jpg  (high quality).
http://img.youtube.com/vi/I-tBhNwVa7w/default.jpg (default).
```

For More detail please visit to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Nice work . Thanks a lot superman .